# AngularJS / DRF - Form sending 'GET' on click instead of 'PUT'

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get my registration form on my website working with a 'PUT' request to my webserver. Initially my code was as shown below.

My HTML form:

```
<form data-ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="registrationController">
    Please enter your device key
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My Javascript:

```
homeApp.controller('registrationController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.text) {
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/v1/device_registration/2345',
                data: '',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            });
            $scope.text = 'changeTextTest';
        };
    };
});
```

On form submission I can see the text change to 'changeTextTest' however in the output in my terminal (from ./manage.py runserver) I can see the output status as 403

```
"PUT /api/v1/device_registration/2345 HTTP/1.1" 403 58
```

I figured this was due to me not sending the CSRF token so I added $cookies to the function scope.

```
homeApp.controller('registrationController', function($scope, $http, $cookies) {
```

Now on submission I get

```
"GET /app/?text=randomInputText HTTP/1.1" 200 2881
```

and the URL in my browser changes to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/?text=randomInputText
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Angular is not actually stopping the original request from being sent. If you take Angular out of the equation, the `<form>` that you have right now will send a GET request that is very similar to the one you are seeing.

Make sure to test that the request is being sent (check using the network monitor in the developer tools of your browser), and also make sure that Angular is actually stopping the underlying GET request from going through. You should also check to make sure that you have the `$cookies` provider included on your page, as not having it could explain why Angular is not intercepting the form submission.

Once you get back to a state where your application is triggering a `PUT` request with the 403 error, check your network monitor again. It should allow you to view the response, which will either tell you that you failed to authenticate or that you have a permission issue. If you failed to authenticate, this most likely means that you are authenticating with `SessionAuthentication`, but are not passing in the CSRF header.

You can tell Angular to inject the special header with the following snippet of code.

```
var my_app = angular.module('myApp', [/* other dependencies */, 'ngCookies']).run(function($http, $cookies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.put['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
});
```

This snippet was pulled from the [django-angular documentation](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf-protection.html#set-header-with-x-csrftoken-via-cookie), but is not specific to the package.

Comment: Thanks for the link to django-angular I did not know that site existed. I fixed my problem. Im not sure what my exact issue was but I included your code shown above, aswell as included 'angular-cookies.js' and it started working.